# Form validation and form action not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have a registering form that collects the user data,
name, surname, email etc, and send this to an email.
However, the validation doesn't seem to work.

My problem is that when the user clicks on submit, even without
typing anything, the page redirects to the form action script page instead of just executing the script in that page.

Any help is welcome.
Mike

The form:

```
  <?php
echo form_open('viewer_registration_email/signup_validation');


echo validation_errors();
    $name_data = array( 
    'name' => 'viewerFirstName',
    'id'   => 'viewerFirstName',
    'value'  => $this->input->post('viewerFirstName'),
    'placeholder' =>"  First Name",
    'class'  => 'customInputFieldSmallHome'
);

$email_data = array(
    'name' => 'viewerEmail',
    'id'   => 'viewerEmail',
    'value'  => $this->input->post('viewerEmail'),
    'placeholder' =>"  Your Email", 
    'class'  => 'customInputFieldHome'
);

echo form_hidden('submit_viewer', 1);
echo '<span style="float:left">';
echo form_input($name_data);
echo '</span><br>';
echo form_input($email_data);

echo form_submit("submit", "", 'class="signUpBtn"');

echo form_close();
?>
```

the controller:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Viewer_registration_email extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
    }
    public function signup_validation()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('viewerFirstName','First Name','required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('viewerEmail','Email','required|trim|valid_email');
        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            $this->load->library('email', array('mailtype' => 'html'));
            $this->email->from('register@mysite.com','My site Registration');
            $this->email->to('mike@mysite.com');
            $this->email->subject('New registered user');
            $birthday = $this->input->post('viewerBirthDay')."/".$this->input->post('viewerBirthMonth') ."/".
            $this->input->post('viewerBirthYear');
            $message = '<div style="width:100%; height:35px; background-color:#558F61;"></div>
                        <br><br><br>
                        <h1>  A new user has registered as a <span style="font-weight:bold">Viewer</span> on Your website.</h1>
                        <br><br><br>
                        <table style="border:none">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span style="font-weight:bold">Name: </span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    '.$this->input->post('viewerFirstName').'
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                  <span style="font-weight:bold">Last name: </span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    '.$this->input->post('viewerLastName').'
                                </td>
                            </tr>   
                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                 <span style="font-weight:bold">Email: </span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    '.$this->input->post('viewerEmail').'
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>    
                        <br><br><br><br>
                        <div style="width:100%; height:35px; background-color:#558F61;"></div>';
            $this->email->message($message);
            //send email to user
            if($this->email->send()){
                //echo "Email has been sent.";
                $this->load->view('confirm_registration_email');
            }else{
                echo 'email failed!';
            }
        }else{
            $this->load->view('home_main');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to say that the url changes to : "viewer_registration_email/signup_validation" and the page is blank. even if data is entered in the fields the same happens, so my guess is that it's failing the validation because it is as if it doen't exist.

Comment: Form's action is `viewer_registration/signup_validation` but controller name is `Viewer_registration_email`. Is this a typo?

Comment: It is just a typo in here, they are both "            'viewer_registration_email"

Comment: Your code appears to work fine when I try it on a test site. Submitting the form with empty fields, or otherwise invalid info, shows the form again with the errors `The First Name field is required. The Email field must contain a valid email address.` If I submit valid info, it attempts to send an email. Is this correct? If so, I think you've got other code that you didn't post above that's interfering with it.

Comment: now I'm having the message : No input file specified.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was with my hosting service settings. Using GoDaddy. I found
the solution here: [Godaddy-Installation-Tips](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Godaddy-Installation-Tips)

thanks for all the replies,

Mike